# Bootstrap modal - strange placement of opened element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a JSFiddle that addresses my issue, [**link here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ofya69sd/1/).

- Open the modal
- Click the chevron
- Close the modal
- Open the modal again

Now you see that the unordered list is placed somewhat strange.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="testBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <h4 id="test-h4"><strong>My header</strong> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test-ul"></i></h4>

                <ul class="list-group collapse" id="test-ul">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <p>Maecenas quis libero turpis. Praesent accumsan suscipit ex, a viverra risus consectetur non. Suspendisse et elit viverra, cursus mauris eget, condimentum ante. Vivamus et libero odio. Nunc a urna mattis, vestibulum urna eu, aliquet nulla. Maecenas sit amet metus pulvinar velit cursus aliquet at non diam. In pretium, sem nec faucibus ullamcorper, arcu nibh semper turpis, quis pulvinar risus libero in enim. Suspendisse ultrices posuere pulvinar.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('.glyphicon-chevron-down').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});

$("#testBtn").click(function () {
    $("#test-ul").addClass('in');
    $("#test-h4").find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    $("#test-h4").find('i').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

I have stripped out all unnecessary code and this is what's important.

> Note: I want the element inside to be opened when I click <kbd>Open
>   Modal</kbd>

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $('#testBtn').on('click', function() {
        $('#test-ul').collapse('show');
  });
```

Comment: This is excellent, really simple and does what I want. Thank you @madalin ivascu

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
$('.glyphicon-chevron-down').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});

$("#testBtn").click(function () {
    $("#test-ul").addClass('in');
    $("#test-h4").find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    $("#test-h4").find('i').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    return:false;
    display:block;
});
```

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/ofya69sd/2/)

Comment: Thanks but this does not fix anything since the element is collapsed when opening it.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has its own methods and events. Is better usign them:

```
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal",function(e){ //<-- event fired when the modal is shown
    $("#test-ul").collapse("show");  //<-- show the collapsible with method
    $("#test-h4").find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');   
});
```

This will fire every time the modal is opened.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ofya69sd/5/)

Have a look at the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: Yeah i've taken a look at them but I did not get anything relevant out of it for my case. Thanks for your response though @ojovirtual